# EmitterProcessor using zip and last(default value) doesn't ever emit values

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to use the `zip` along with the `last` operators to combine three different `EmitterProcessor` and process the combined result. This has worked perfect as defined below except in the scenario where one of the processors doesn't emit an item. My understanding of the `last(defaultValue)` operator is that it will emit the default value when the `EmitterProcessor` completes without ever emitting a value. This should in turn complete the `zip` and send the default value along with any actual values from the other processors. The issue is the zip never completes after the `complete` call is executed on all the processors. Am I missing something or is there a bug somewhere in the Reactor code?

```
EmitterProcessor.zip(
    emitter1.last("Missing Value 1"),
    emitter2.last("Missing Value 2"),
    emitter3.last("Missing Value 3")
).subscribe {
    logger.error(it.t1)
    logger.error(it.t2)
    logger.error(it.t3)
}

// Later in the code I call complete on all emitters
emitter1.sink().complete()
emitter2.sink().complete()
emitter3.sink().complete()
```

Comment: This actually turned out to be a bug in Project Reactor related to the last operator. I submitted a PR with the fix (https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/2020) which should be released with version 3.2.x

Answer (score 0):

Maybe combineLatest would solve your problem. Note you should at least emit 1 value to each processor

```
   EmitterProcessor<String> emitter1= EmitterProcessor.create();
    EmitterProcessor<String> emitter2= EmitterProcessor.create();
    EmitterProcessor<String> emitter3= EmitterProcessor.create();

    EmitterProcessor.zip(
            emitter1.defaultIfEmpty("Missing Value 1"),
            emitter2.defaultIfEmpty("Missing Value 2"),
            emitter3.defaultIfEmpty("Missing Value 3")
    ).log();
EmitterProcessor.combineLatest(emitter1, emitter2, emitter3, objects -> {
return objects;
}).log().subscribe();

    emitter1.onNext("a");
    emitter2.onNext("a");

    emitter3.onNext("a");

    emitter1.onNext("a");
    emitter1.onNext("a");
    emitter1.onNext("a");
    emitter1.onNext("a");
    emitter1.onNext("a");

   // Later in the code I call complete on all emitters
    emitter1.sink().complete();
    emitter2.sink().complete();
    emitter3.sink().complete();
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer @ricard-kollcaku but for my specific use case I need the last element emitted or the default value if no elements emitted. While your solution does emit the default item if empty it also takes the first emitted item if any of the streams emit multiple items instead of the last one.